# Cant add custom class to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I have a custom class called PLAYER which has the following properties with the associated getter and setter and default init.

```
Private aName As String
Private aAge As Integer
Private aID As String
Private aScore As Integer
```

I am now trying to create an array in the main program as follows:

```
    Dim Players As Range
    Set Players = Range("PLAYERS")

    Dim PlayerRows As Integer, PlayerCols As Integer, count As Integer

    PlayerRows = Players.Rows.count

    Dim allPlayers() As PLAYER
    ReDim allPlayers(5)

    Dim temp As New PLAYER
    temp.name = Players.Cells(count + 1, 1)
    temp.age = Players.Cells(count + 1, 2)
    temp.ID = Players.Cells(count + 1, 3)
    temp.score = Players.Cells(count + 1, 4)

    allPlayers(0) = temp
```

But when I try and add the new object to to array of PLAYER objects I get a runtime error 91 'Object variable or With Block variable not set'.

How am I setting up this array wrong? I am trying to have an array for the class PLAYER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with objects you have to use “Set” keyword:

```
Set allPlayers(0) = temp
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. One more quick point if I was to do this and try add the players to a list it looks to add the last player to even index in the list:

 ` 
    Do While (endLoop = False)
    
        Dim temp As New PLAYER
        temp.name = Players.Cells(count + 1, 1)
    
        If ((count + 1) = PlayerRows) Then
            endLoop = True
        End If
    
       Set allPlayers(count) = temp
       count = count + 1
        
    Loop••••ˇˇˇˇ
 `

Comment: Post a new question